# GITHUB ACTIONS ERROR: firebase.json file not found, while trying to deploy to firebase

Tags: firebase, yaml, devops, github-actions

I am trying to automate the deploy process with github actions in my repo, and when I run the deploy.yml file it gives me this error:

```
firebase.json file not found. If your firebase.json file is not in the root of your repo, edit the entryPoint option of this GitHub action.
```

deploy.yml code:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on new release 
'on': release
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          entryPoint: "./demo"
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_*****_***** }}'
          projectId: *************
```

I have no idea whats wrong here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you list your files right before the deploy step, do you see the firebase.json listed? It seems your options are correct.

Comment: This command: - run: ls  ./demo